# Disable default autostart scripts via console commands

Tags: 14.04, xfce, autostart

I have a fully unattended Ubuntu Install process in place that installs xfce for me and then some other stuff. My only problem: while I can add new startup scrips by just copying them to ~/.config/autostart, there are also some programs listed in Autostart-Manager gui that comes with xfce4. Is there a way to disable these default scripts (specially: update notification) only using console commands so I can copy that in my install script?

I looked at everything xfconf-query has to offer but there does not seem to be a function for this application.
These scripts are also neither in ~/.config/autostart nor in ~/Desktop/Autostart

Comment: Have you tried copying the `update-notifier.desktop` to your `~/.config/autostart` and then changing the `NotShowIn` property to include `XFCE`?

Comment: They're probably in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Comment: Thanks @muru, did not know about that folder and sure enough, there it was!

Comment: @Teekeks excellent! If you could post an answer showing how you disabled those entries, it would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Help of @muru I found a solution.

Besides ~/.config/autostart/ and ~/Desktop/Autostart/, there is a third Folder, /etc/xdg/autostart/ with scripts. I ended up just deleting the ones that I do not need.

To be exact, I used this command as root to disable the Update Notifier:

```
rm -f /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
```

Comment: good answer, but using `sudo` instead of root would be better for some "purist" Ubuntu users :D

Comment: I still think it would be better to disable them *locally* - if you simply remove files from the /etc/xdg/autostart directory there's a chance they will be reinstalled during subsequent package updates (not to mention confusing the package management system)